# Java String.replace/replaceAll not working

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

So, I'm trying to parse a String input in Java that contains (opening) square brackets. I have `str.replace("\\[", "")`, but this does absolutely nothing. I've tried `replaceAll` also, with more than one different regex, but the output is always unchanged. Part of me wonders if this is possibly caused by the fact that all my back-slash characters appear as yen symbols (ever since I added Japanese to my languages), but it's been that way for over a year and hasn't caused me any issues like this before.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java. Make sure you re-assign the return value to the same `String` variable:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "");
```

For the normal `replace` method, you don't need to escape the bracket:

```
str = str.replace("[", "");
```

Comment: Yes, the clue is in the return type, uchuujin: why would `replaceAll` return String if it modified the String in place; shouldn't it be `void`?

Answer (score 2):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

As shown in the code above, replaceAll method expects first argument as regular expression and hence you need to escape characters like "**(**", "**)**" etc (with "**\**") if these exists in your replacement text which is to be replaced out of the string. For example :

```
String oldString = "This is (stringTobeReplaced) with brackets.";

String newString = oldString.replaceAll("\\(stringTobeReplaced\\)", "");
System.out.println(newString); // will output "This is  with brackets."
```

Another way of doing this is to use Pattern.quote("str") :

```
    String newString = oldString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("(stringTobeReplaced)"), "");
```

This will consider the string as literal to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

As always, the problem is not that "xxx doesn't work", it is that you don't know how to use it.

First things first:

- a `String` is immutable; if you read the javadoc of `.replace()` and `.replaceAll()`, you will see that both specify that *a new `String` instance is returned*;
- `replace()` accepts *a string literal* as its first argument, not a regex literal.

Which means that you probably meant to do:

```
str = str.replace("[", "");
```

If you only ever do:

```
str.replace("[", "");
```

then the new instance will be created but you ignore it...

---

In addition, and this is a common trap with `String` (the other being that `.matches()` is misnamed), in spite of their respective names, `.replace()` *does* replace all occurrences of its first argument with its second argument; the only difference is that `.replaceAll()` accepts a regex as a first argument, and a "regex aware" expression as its second argument; for more details, see the javadoc of `Matcher`'s `.replaceAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

For it to work it has to be inside a method.

for example:

```
public class AnyClass {
    String str = "gtrg4\r\n" + "grtgy\r\n" + "grtht\r\n" + "htrjt\r\n" + "jtyjr\r\n" + "kytht";

    public String getStringModified() {
        str.replaceAll("\r\n", "");

        return str;
    }
}
```