# Replace all √num from a string java

Tags: java

I have a string that contains `String q = "What's the value of √32 and √83?";`, my problem is replacing `√num` with `sqrt(32)` and `sqrt(83)`.

That means my string should output : -

`What's the value of sqrt(32) and sqrt(83)`

is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to replace it programatically? like find every sqrt symble and replace it with `sqrt()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java String.replace/replaceAll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975776/java-string-replace-replaceall-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regex replacement on the pattern `√(\d+)\b`, and replace with `sqrt(...)`:

```
String q = "What's the value of √32 and √83?";
String output = q.replaceAll("√(\\d+)\\b", "sqrt($1)");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
What's the value of sqrt(32) and sqrt(83)?
```

Comment: Why ``\\b``? Seems unnecessary.