# Replace all √num from a string JavScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that contains `String q = "What's the value of √32 and √83?";`, my problem is replacing √num with sqrt(32) and sqrt(83).

That means my string should output:

`What's the value of sqrt(32) and sqrt(83)`

Actually, one question for me was answered in Java:

[Replace all √num from a string java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383959/replace-all-%E2%88%9Anum-from-a-string-java)

When I try to do the same in JS, it's not changed:

Comment: You need a regex literal: `.replace(/√(\d+)\b/g, "sqrt($1)")`

Comment: Yes, I know, but regex should have worked?

Comment: Okay, will try...

Comment: thanks worked, why did you vote negative :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: nope, its not mine

Comment: I didn't downvote, but reading only a tiny bit about regular expressions in JavaScript would have given you the hint that you should use a regex literal, not a string (although that is also possible, but then you need to call the RegExp constructor). We appreciate when people do their research.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: Why should they work? The regular expression doesn't match anything in those strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help

```
"What's the value of √32 and √83".replaceAll( /√(\d+)/g ,"sqrt($1)");
```

`√` matches the word with √ in the beginning. It can be accessed with `$&`

`(\d+)` matches digits inside previously matched string. It can be accessed with `$1`

`/g` to match all the occurrences